# Finding node voltages of transistor

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

I have the following problem, it consists of BJTs connected in the following way. I am being asked to find the node voltages. Am doing the part were beta=100 and R is connected.

[image: Problem]

I have done the work on my paper, but the problem is that when am simulating it, the simulation results don't match my hand written work. Below are the simulation schematic results using LTSpice. Unfortunately I cannot provide my hand written work here because I have done a lot of circuit conversions. I was hoping if somebody can help me with the analysis mathematically. I would really appreciated that. Thanks in advance.

[image: simulation]
[image: simulation results]

[image: SPICE Netlist]

Comment: Can you paste the spice netlist?

Comment: just added that

Comment: Add the hand-written work product. Math and numbers can be communicated clearly regardless of native language.

Comment: Just a note, by the way. The simulator isn't going to come up with your figures. It won't do \$\beta=\infty\$, for example. Take a look at the base node of \$Q_1\$. With no base current, and using exact \$700\:\text{mV}\$ for \$D_1\$, this should be \$40\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot \frac{9\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}}{80\:\text{k}\Omega+40\:\text{k}\Omega}+700\:\text{mV}=3.4\overline{6}\:\text{V}\$. Note that the simulator didn't find that node voltage per your problem.

Comment: @jonk. Thank you for you comment, but am not doing Beta=infinity case. Per the question am doing the beta=100 and R is connected

Comment: Handwritten work product, please.

Comment: Also, how did you get all your PN junctions to simulate at exactly .7 V?

Comment: I was hoping if somebody would post the mathematical analysis for this problem because am trying really hard and not finding the solution to match the simulation

Comment: Understood. But it takes a lot of work to prepare a complete solution. If you post your work, seeing it might save others a lot of precious time. You are asking for help. Respect the time of those you want help from, by showing what you have done.

Comment: Do you still need help with this? Which transistor model / equations are you using? Can you replace the SPICE image with the text for pasting this directly? Can you paste the hand results you are getting?

Comment: Yeah please I was hoping somebody would help with the mathematical analysis to get numbers that match the simulation output. Thanks man

Comment: am just using the generic PNP and NPN available at LT Spice. I used the .model directive to specify the beta. That's pretty much it. I used this way for my other problems and it was giving me accurate answers in terms of my mathematical analysis

Comment: I am still curious on the equations you used. Can you also paste the SPICE code as text? and paste some final results you get by hand?